# error 1004 excel 2010: unable to set the visible property of the pivotitem class

Tags: excel, pivot, visible

I cannot make my code working because of the so famous errore above. I was unable to find a solution reading previous posts, so hope anyone can help me.

I have several pivot tables (pt) in different worksheets (ws), and a list of items stored in an array I created.
I've written a macro for setting ON all items in pt except those ones in the array (listOffnet within the code). Everything works properly.

Now, I would like to do the complementary action: setting OFF all items that are not in the array.
Unfortunately, I get the error at line

```
pvtItm.Visible = False
```

Many thanks!
This is my code:

```
Sub ptFilterOffnet()

Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable
Dim pvtItm As PivotItem
Dim pvtFld As String
Dim listItem As Variant
Dim listOffnet As Variant
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim myws As String

pvtFld = "CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION"
myws = "GESTIONE_ADMIN"

resetSlicers 'function resetting all slicers connected to pivot tables (all items ON)

' Populate the array with some data in a specific range
lastRow = Sheets(myws).Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row
listOffnet = populateArray(myws, 3, lastRow, 10, 10)

' All OFF but items within listOffnet
For Each PvtTbl In Sheets("P1").PivotTables
    For Each pvtItm In PvtTbl.PivotFields(pvtFld).PivotItems
        For Each listItem In listOffnet
            If pvtItm <> listItem Then
                pvtItm.Visible = False
            End If
        Next      
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of taking the range of "off" values and putting them into an array, try just referencing that range in your For Each loop.  For example, this worked for me:

```
For Each PvtTbl In Sheets("P1").PivotTables
    For Each pvtItm In PvtTbl.PivotFields(pvtFld).PivotItems
        For Each listItem In Range("OffList").Cells
            If pvtItm <> listItem Then
                pvtItm.Visible = False
            End If
        Next
    Next
Next
```

The difference is in the 3rd line.

If that doesn't work, you may want to try [changing the Sort parameter](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/error-1004-pivotitems-visible-t2246575.html) or [any of the proposed solutions in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11468705/493055).