# How to filter pivot table with multiple items?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am trying to filter data from a pivot table. Why does the first setting work and the 2nd one does not? error is "unable to set the visible property in the PivotItem class"
should I be doing this any differently? 
ultimately I want to filter based on a string and apply the correct settings to filter.

```
Sub Macro11()
'

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Brand").CurrentPage = _
        "(All)"
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Brand")
   .PivotItems("BK").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("CV").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("CV R").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("GC").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("OS").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("CL").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("CL R").Visible = False

    End With




    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Brand").CurrentPage = _
        "(All)"
  With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Brand")
   .PivotItems("Bk").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("CV").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("CV R").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("GC").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("OS").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("CL").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("CL R").Visible = True

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: have you googled "unable to set the visible property in the PivotItem class" to help with troubleshooting?  Without more context (and data examples), this looks to have some promising things to try:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468705/unable-to-set-the-visible-property-of-the-pivotitem-class-vba

Comment: Looks like I just need to add this to each one   `.ClearAllFilters 
        .EnableMultiplePageItems = True `

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this works...

```
Sub Macro11()

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Brand")
        .ClearAllFilters
        .EnableMultiplePageItems = True
        .PivotItems("BK").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("CV").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("CV R").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("GC").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("OS").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("CL").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("CL R").Visible = False

    End With


  With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Brand")
        .ClearAllFilters
        .EnableMultiplePageItems = True
        .PivotItems("Bk").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("CV").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("CV R").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("GC").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("OS").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("CL").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("CL R").Visible = True

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: this actually still had issues. see my final code posted above

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test()

Dim PI As PivotItem
Dim myArray() As Variant
Dim i As Integer

myArray = Array("BK", "GC", "OS", "CL", "CL R")

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Brand")
    .ClearManualFilter
    .EnableMultiplePageItems = True

    For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
        .PivotItems(myArray(i)).Visible = False
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

or you can use another approach

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Brand")
        For Each PI In .PivotItems
            If PI.Name <> "CV" Then PI.Visible = False
        Next PI
 End With
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what ultimately worked for me:

```
For Each PT In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
    PTname = PT.Name
    Next
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(PTname).PivotFields("Brand")
        .ClearAllFilters
        .EnableMultiplePageItems = True
        For Each pvtitem In .PivotItems
        If pvtitem.Name = "OS" Then
            pvtitem.Visible = True
            Else
            pvtitem.Visible = False
           End If
          Next
    End With
```